# "Clicking 'Log Out' will log you out of the following domains on this device:"

Tags: bug, logout

Hamburger menu → Log Out

Message:

> Clicking 'Log Out' will log you out of the following domains on this device"

- This message is incorrect. Clicking "Log out" will just log you out of the current *browser* and not across everything "on this device".
- This is relevant because many people use several browsers simultaneously, in the same logged-in session. Logging out SO in Firefox doesn't log SO out of Chrome..
- Also, two simultaenous logged-in sessions (i.e. logged in as `user1` and `user2` on macOS with fast user switching) is all happening on the same device. I can be logged in to the same Stackoverflow account with two different browsers in two different logged-in sessions. The wording in the message implies all of those are logged out, too.

I know this snowball fast when you also consider virtualized environments (OSes, browser Tab encapsulation/containers..). Each with their *own* set of possible multiple simultaenous logged-in sessions, browsers. Add to this the fact Stack Exchange has hundreds of communities each with individual auth tokens.

Of course I have suggestions for how this could be solved *differently*, but that is more for a feature request type discussion. What's on point here is that when users click "log out", the feedback from the system need to be factually correct. Just changing the text to read "... in this browser session" could be a start? Caveat: english is not my first language. I know this is semantic in nature, but as it is related to the security around user accounts, it's important to get correct.

[image: Logoutmessage]

Comment: The browser _session_ ends when the browser is closed (without crashing); restarting it starts a new session, which usually doesn’t log you out. If you set a browser preference to clear cookies every time you quit the browser, then you’ll have to log in again, but the record with the credentials cookies may still remain on the server, so providing the auth cookies manually makes it appear as if you’re still logged in. Only clicking “Log out” clears this record from the server (after a few seconds of caching). It’s complicated. “Browser” would already be an improvement, though.